# Can ArcGIS ModelBuilder be exported to Python and run in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, pyqgis, modelbuilder

Is it possible to construct a geoalgorithm on the ArcMap ModelBuilder, export this entire algorithm to python syntax (without having ANY knowledge of python) and then import this algorithm to QGIS and run it successfully?

I am more familiar with ArcGIS Desktop and unfortunately the QGIS Processing framework presents enormous difficulties when using GRASS commands to process raster files. I for one am not familiar with GRASS, and the QGIS processing framework is unable to take care of the GRASS part for me when it comes to dealing with rasters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question is easily answered by using the following steps:

1. Construct a simple model using the ArcGIS ModelBuilder
2. Export this model to Python syntax which you can do without having ANY knowledge of Python because it is an option on the ModelBuilder menu
3. Try running the same script with QGIS and address any Python/QGIS errors thrown as they arise

Unless the model you start out with is very simple, even performing step 3 using ArcGIS for Desktop can be very challenging for someone new to Python, so my answer to your question of doing that for QGIS becomes close to an unqualified "No".